# Is possible to format a date without the date

Tags: php, laravel

I usually use this to format dates:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $request->id_input);
```

---

Is it possible to format a date without the date; only the time? 
I had tried this, from [Manual PHP DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('H\hi\m \s', $request->sel)->format('H:i:s');
```

This doesn't work. It throws an error that says:

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\

 FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)

 Call to a member function format() on boolean
```

---

I have a `select` with some options as in the following example:

```
<select name="sel">
  <option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option>
  <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
  <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
</select>
```

I have a `select` to select the time and the date is in another input.

Finally, I try to save the record into my database in MySQL. This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $schedules = new SchedulesNew();

    try {

        $schedules->id = $request->id;

        $schedules->court_id = $request->court_checkbox;

        /*___________________________________________________________*/

        $hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('H\hi\m \s', $request->sel)->format('H:i:s');
        $schedules->start_time =$request->date_input + $hour;

        $hour2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H\h i\m s\s', $request->sel2)->format('H:i:s');
        $schedules->end_time = $request->date_input_end + $hour2;

        $schedules->state_schedule_id = $request->state_schedule_id;

        $schedules->save();



    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'There was an unknown error');

         return redirect()->route('schedules.store');

    }

        Session::flash('message', "The record was saved successfully");
        return redirect()->route('schedules.store');

}
```

If I don't convert the time that I received from the select, my website shows me an error that says:

**`A non well formed numeric value encountered`**

On these lines:

```
 $schedules->start_time =$request->date_input + $request->sel;

 $schedules->end_time = $request->date_input_2 + $request->sel2;
```

That is the reason that **I think** I need to convert to a time format, not a date format.

Comment: The values of your dropdown do not seem to match the format you're passing to `createFromFormat()`

Comment: Are you sure the format of `H\hi\m \s` is valid?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @M4uriXD... you added a link?  Why?

Comment: Your update doesn't change the fact that your format doesn't match your data.

Comment: Your select options' values are already in the H:i:s format.  This question makes no sense.

Comment: @Devon. Because you asked that `H\hi\m \s` was valid and at the end o f the page explain how you can use it.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `$hour` to be after calling that line?

Comment: As you want to create a DateTime Object the answer is NO, you can't create a DateTime object only by providing the time, at least is not possible using the native DateTime Object from PHP. But you can append a string with some date to your hour field and complete a full date that can be parsed to DateTime object

Comment: @M4uriXD, so you copied a random line from the manual with no consideration for what the input format was?

Comment: @Devon. As I explained before, I was trying it and I didn't know very well how can I do it.

Comment: Trying what?  You don't even need to convert to H:i:s because you already have H:i:s... did you read the manual or just skim it?  The point of the line you're referencing is to convert a format of `23h 15m 03s` to `23:15:03`... you already have a `23:15:03` type format..

Comment: @PatrickQ. I updated the question again. Because you asked what I expect to achieve with my question.

Comment: Okay, but you still didn't provide what I asked for. If I picked the "09:00:00" option in your dropdown, what do you expect the value of `$hour` to be after doing `$hour = DateTime::createFromFormat('H\hi\m \s', $request->sel)->format('H:i:s');`?

Comment: @Devon. I explained that it doesn't work as it is, that is why I tried to convert the received value to the time format.

Comment: No you really didn't explain it.   Your attempt of conversion is useless because you don't need to convert.   There's absolutely no point as has been pointed out to you.  You are also using an arithmetic operator to try to add two date strings together.  To me, it's obvious that you are attempting things before actually taking the time to learn the language.  You should really take a class and have a teacher or mentor to reach out to.

Comment: @PatrickQ. I try to save it into my table schedules, there are 2 select, it's a range, for example. 09:00:00 to 10:00:00 it's the time that, for example, the tennis court there was reserved and no one else can use it between that time, except for the person or entity that reserved the tennis court.

Comment: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"  You are getting this error because you are attempting to perform addition (`+`) on two _strings_.  The concatenation operator in PHP is the dot (`.`).  Please take some time to review the PHP manual, specifically the [section on string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: @PatrickQ. Thanks now it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Laravel, try with Carbon like this:

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "08:00:00");
```

this is the response

```
=> Carbon\Carbon {#1226
    "date": "2018-10-30 08:00:00.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "UTC",
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the whole `DateTime::createFromFormat()` part of your code in parenthesis. Like this:

```
$hour = (DateTime::createFromFormat('H\hi\m \s', $request->sel))->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Oh sorry about that, you should also swap the formats like this:

      $hour = (DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $request->sel))->format('H\hi\m \s');